# MySQL uses empty username in the connection error message

Tags: mysql

I found a strange mysql behaviour I am struggling to explain

```
[vagrant@Subs ~]$ mysql -u root12 subdb
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'subdb'
```

It uses empty string *''* as the user name in the error message even though I explicitly supplied *root12*. If I provide the right username it connects with no problems so I suspect it is just the way mysql reports the error.

Is this a bug or undocumented feature?

```
[vagrant@Subs ~]$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

**EDIT**

People seem to be confused by the wording of this question. I am using root12 as the username, not the password. I am also saying mysql there is no password for *root12*. Furthermore, root12 user does not even exist. So it is a clear authentication failure. My question is why instad of saying

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root12'@'localhost' to database 'subdb'
```

it says

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'subdb'
```

**EDIT**

Running CentOS6.5, mysql 5.1.73 here. *testuser* user does not originally exist

```
[vagrant@Subs ~]$ mysql -u testuser subdb
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'subdb'

[vagrant@Subs ~]$ mysql -u root

...

mysql> CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
[vagrant@Subs ~]$ mysql -u testuser subdb
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It's clear from this output that MySQL (seems like only this version) is leaking info whether the username exists or not. If it does not exist the error message resets the username to empty string. If it does, mysql keeps the username intact

Comment: @Drew These are steps to repro the error message. I am causing the authentication error because I need mysql to give me the error message.

Answer (score 0):

try as per below-

```
mysql -u root12 -p
```

It will ask you password and you need to supply root12 password.

but if root12 is password of root user then use below command-

```
mysql -u root -proot12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not trying to use a password for the root12 user, I am trying to understand why the error message does not use the username given but uses empty string instead.

Comment: @Drew This is correct - there is no password for the user. root12 user does not exist user so the error message is absoultely expected. My question is why instead of saying Access denied for user 'root12'@'localhost' it says Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (note empty username)?

Comment: @VladimirHraban: here error message is "Access denied for user ''@'localhost'" means mysql is showing user as '' instead of root12 it means mysql is not getting any valid user here...

Comment: @ZafarMalik your last comment seems to answer Vlad's question, although you don't say whether this behaviour is documented. It might be worth posting it as an answer.  (I don't personally know whether its accurate)

Comment: @Drew, thanks, I created a password protected test user, tried to log in with no password and mysql did not change the username to empty string.  Wonder if it documented, but MySQL seems to leak whether the user exists or not