# How do I select the MySQL database after logging in to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I enter with the root user, with the command mysql -u root . When I log in and try to select the mysql database with command USE mysql, it does not give me access.

I log in with a root account, but as '' @ 'localhost' it shows

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Comment: Don't you have a typo? In the message there is a `musql`

Comment: We have too less information. Which operating system are we talking about? how did you install MariaDB? Which user are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like very similar to he one described and solved at the following : [MySQL uses empty username in the connection error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454849/mysql-uses-empty-username-in-the-connection-error-message)

I would recommend, if not done already, to run mariadb-secure-installation to set a password for root and make sure it is declared in the mysql.user table.

To get connected, I would then recommend to enter the following command :

```sh
mariadb -A -uroot -p -Dmysql
```